# In a semi-metric space, need the limit of a sequence be unique as it is in a metric space? Yes

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

In a metric space (M,d), define what you mean by a bounded set B and by L being the limit of a sequence $\{x_n\} \in M$. What is the sequential definition of a function between two metric spaces being continuous? In a semi-metric space, need the limit of a sequence be unique as it is in a metric space?

$\textbf{What is the sequential definition of a function between two metric spaces being continuous?}$

Let $f:(M,d) \to (K,D)$ be a function between two metric spaces. Then f is called sequentially continuous if for each sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in M with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=L$. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=f(L)$. This corresponds to the usual pictorial definition. This is equivalent to inverse image of open is open using metric spaces.

$\textbf{In a semi-metric space, need the limit of a sequence be unique as it is in a metric space?}$

$\textbf{Claim:}$ In a semi-metric space, the limit of a sequence doesn't need to be unique as in a metric space.

$\textbf{Example:}$ Let $m=\{$convergent sequences of complex numbers$\}$. Let the metric d on m be $d(\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty, \{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty)=|\alpha-\beta|$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=\alpha$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n=\beta$. However this set can't be a metric space because it fails the first property because $x_n$ and $y_n$ an have the same limit but not be equal to one another.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ I am unsure how to formally prove that the sequences do not have to be unqiue. I know that the typical way of proving uniqueness is by assuming that there are two distinct elements and showing that they must be equal. How would I do such a thing for this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a semi-metric space which is not a metric space. Then there exist $x,y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y) = 0$. The sequence $(x_n)_n$ which is given by $x_{2n} = x$ and $x_{2n+1} = y$ has the property $d(x_n,x) = 0 = d(x_n, y)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ as well as to $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Just construct a sequence in $m$ that converges to more than one point. This is easy, since any sequence in $m$ that converges at all converges to infinitely many different points. For instance, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_n$ be the zero sequence $z=\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$. Obvious $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $z$. Can you write down explicitly at least one other member of $m$ to which $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges?

**Added:** As bof reminds me, I should probably point out that a function that is like a metric except that it may not separate points is normally called a *pseudometric*; the term *semimetric* is usually used for a function that is symmetric and separates points but need not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: I was really confused by this question until I figured out that it's talking about pseudometrics. Are pseudometrics really called semimetrics these days? If so, what are semimetrics called?

Comment: @bof: I’ve not seen them called semimetrics before this; I was just going with the question. I should probably add a note about terminology. (I assume that you, like me, use *semimetric* for what you get when you drop the triangle inequality.)